# How to handle scroll smoothly with multiple UITableView inside UIPageViewController that is inside UIScrollView in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am struggling to fix the scrolling in a UI like following:

UIViewController

-- UIScrollView

---- ContainerView

------ UIPageViewController

-------- UITableView 1

-------- UITableView 2

-------- UITableView 3

My requirement is

- A header view on top
- Following a Tab View
- 3 Tabs that contains UITableView

Any one can suggest a proper approach to design such a layout and a way to handling a scroll in such way that vertical scroll should scroll smoothly but it should fix the Tab View on top while scrolling down and unfix the tab view when scrolling up..

Note: I don't want to give UIScrollView a fix content size because in this way UITableView loose the reusability of its cell.